# image_proc warning /camera/camera/

Tags: ros, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am receiving warnings from image_proc every 30 seconds or so:

[ WARN] [1310053249.262781753]: The input topic '/camera/camera/image_raw' is not yet advertised

[ WARN] [1310053249.262963275]: The input topic '/camera/camera/camera_info' is not yet advertised

Note the doubling of 'camera'.

The prosilica_camera node is publishing /camera/image_raw and /camera/camera/info, and image_proc is subscribed to them with no problem, other than the persistent warnings. I am launching the nodes with:

```
<launch>
  <node name="launch_prosilica_camera" pkg="prosilica_camera" type="prosilica_node" output="screen">
    <param name="~trigger_mode" type="str" value="streaming"/>
  </node>
  <node name="launch_image_proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" output="screen">
    <env name="ROS_NAMESPACE" value="camera"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

It could be me, but I think this behavior just began recently, perhaps due to an update.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10513/image_proc-warning-/camera/camera/.../) by [prp](https://answers.ros.org/users/706/prp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, found it. Not sure why the behavior changed recently, but the fix is to launch image_proc in the "/camera" name space, not in "camera". The modified .launch file is:

```
<launch>
  <node name="launch_prosilica_camera" pkg="prosilica_camera" type="prosilica_node" output="screen">
    <param name="~trigger_mode" type="str" value="streaming"/>
  </node>
  <node name="launch_image_proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" output="screen">
    <env name="ROS_NAMESPACE" value="/camera"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Thanks for the views!

---

Originally posted by [prp](https://answers.ros.org/users/706/prp/) with karma: 118 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-09**:
It's also recommended to use the  roslaunch tag instead of the ROS_NAMESPACE environment variable.